# trying to addFile in plupload using input field of type file

Tags: plupload

I've used plupload with its browse button option successfully, but I am now trying to use the utility to resize files within an existing web page where the user individually selects files.
I understood from the documentation that the uploader addFile method would work with input fields but I'm having no success.

The field is defined as:

```
<input id="SelectUserFile1" name="userfile1" type="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg" aria-labelledby="SelectUserFile1-ariaLabel" title="Browse for file on your computer" />
```

and I add the file with:

```
uploader.init();
uploader.addFile(document.getElementById('SelectUserFile1'));
alert('files total: ' + uploader.files.length);
uploader.start();
```

It seems to fail though, as my FilesAdded method is not called and uploader.files.length is 0.
My uploader is defined as follows:

```
var filecount = 1;
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url : 'test_file_upload.php',
    flash_swf_url : '../testjs/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '../testjs/Moxie.xap',
    resize: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    },
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '5mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif"}
        ]
    },

    // PreInit events, bound before any internal events
    preinit: {

        UploadFile: function(up, file) {
            //log('[UploadFile]', file);

            // You can override settings before the file is uploaded
            up.settings.url = 'test_file_upload.php?cnt=' + filecount;
            filecount = filecount + 1;
        }
    },

    init: {

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            alert('files added: ' + up.files.length);
        },

        Error: function(up, err) {
            alert( err.message + ' File not included.' );
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?